# Adding a data Grid View to user form

Tags: c#, vb.net, user-controls

I need to use a form multiple times so i created a user control ( **Lets Call It UC1**) which i Dragged and dropped a table from data sources window so visual studio automatically creates the required binding source ad link it to data grid . Every time i create a new UC1 object , it automatically creates the data grid View but the binding source isn't linked to it so its just an empty data grid view ( The Column names are there but the data grid doesn't show any records) . How Can i fix this ? 
I have tried adding the binding Source with code but didn't change the result

Comment: 1. To use a form multiple times just use the form multiple times; you don't need a user control. 2. when you drag the dataset to the form in the designer you will also get some simple code to populate the grid. It's up to you to modify or add your own code to populate the grid in the way you want.

Comment: Don't bother with the UserControl - you are just adding pointless complexity. Any time you need the form, just do a Dim f as new frmMyForm: f.showdialog: f.dispose .
Get that working first, then turn to the data access. When you have done the drag n drop, the bindingsource will be connected to the grid and to a design-time representation of the dataset. YOu don't need to change the bs with code, but you might want to pass  the dataset at runtime, and set the datasource of the bs to this dataset instead of the design-time one.

Comment: @peterG What if you are using User Controls to separate the pieces of your UI into isolated pieces, to encapsulate UI-related logic and naming? Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @Sam Selikoff Under normal circs the form itself does that, and you would locate the rest of your non-presentation-layer code in a class - IMO you only need a usercontrol if you have a complex piece of UI *that you are going to use in multiple places*, and in the nature of things this doesn't often arise - you'd typically have one form to do one job, called perhaps from multiple places.